# Getting element with max property from array

Tags: arrays, swift, max

If I have a struct...

```
struct MyStruct {
    let number: Int
}
```

and I have an array of them...

```
var array = [MyStruct]()
// populate array with MyStructs
```

Then I can do this to get the maximum `number`...

```
var maxNumber = 0

for tempStruct in array where tempStruct.number > maxNumber {
    maxNumber = tempStruct.number
}
```

However, I can't use...

```
let maxStruct = array.maxElement()
```

because `MyStruct` is not comparable. I could make it comparable but then I might also have a date stamp that I want to compare by so making it Comparable isn't ideal.

Is there another way I could do this that is more elegant?

....

I just thought, I could also do this...

```
let maxStruct = array.sort{$0.number > $1.number}.first()
```

But this will take more time. I'm not sure which sort method it uses but it'll prob be `n log(n)` whereas my initial method will just be `n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with `sort()/sortInPlace()`, there are also two variants of `min/maxElement()`: The first
requires that the sequence elements are comparable:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Comparable {

    public func minElement() -> Self.Generator.Element?
    public func maxElement() -> Self.Generator.Element?
}
```

The second has no such restriction and takes the comparator
as an argument instead:

```
extension SequenceType {

    public func minElement(@noescape isOrderedBefore: (Self.Generator.Element, Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self.Generator.Element?
    public func maxElement(@noescape isOrderedBefore: (Self.Generator.Element, Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self.Generator.Element?
}
```

In your case, you can use `maxElement()` with a comparator function:

```
// Swift 2:
let maxStruct = array.maxElement { $0.number < $1.number }
// Swift 3:
let maxStruct = array.max { $0.number < $1.number }
```

Comment: Ah! Awesome, I didn't know I could use `maxElement()` that way. Thanks